# Alt and Windows key swap for MacBook

Tags: windows-7, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to be able to swap my <kbd>cmd</kbd>, or what would be my Windows' key with my <kbd>alt</kbd> key, using AutoHotKey, thus making it more like a real Windows machine.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: wwho -1'd me lol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/); this works on my early 2011 Macbook Pro running Windows 7 x64. The problem is that when you connect an external keyboard to your Macbook, the keys will be screwed up the other way around; it seems that Apple has wired the keyboard that way in hardware.

Comment: this did the trick, the other didn't

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotKey can do that. There are lots of examples online. You probably need the keynames `RAlt`, `LAlt`, `LWin`, and `RWin`.

I use

```
LCtrl::LAlt
LAlt::LCtrl
Rctrl::RAlt
RAlt::RCtrl
```

on Windows to put the keyboard shortcut key in the 'right' place as a Mac user.

Comment: sadly this didn't work. I tried along these lines already. ALl this does it more or less crashes my laptop. All buttons act as if they were being clicked with the windows key and alt is just broken.

Comment: This works fine for me on Windows 7 so it sounds like there's something wrong with your setup.